# .Net Core / Angular CLI - NPM Build Automation (html to cshtml)

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, angular-cli, npm-scripts

I am developing a build process using .Net Core (netcoreapp1.1) and Angular CLI (1.0.1) using npm scripts in Visual Studio 2017.

Is it possible to script npm to take the contents of the Index.html body tag (from the file created by Angular CLI) and place it into the body of a .cshtml file?

Ideally, I would like to use npm scripts exclusively and move away from Gulp, but I can accept a Gulp solution if necessary.

Update for clarification: 
My objective is to include the necessary scripts from the Index.html file created by Angular CLI into a pre-existing cshtml View that has some code that I need to keep.

If it is necessary to create a new file, is there a way to parse the data from two existing files (html and cshtml) and join them into one? I really just need the scripts from the body of the html added to my View.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're not going to be adding any server code to the generated HTML and you're really just looking to rename file, then it could be as simple as using the CLI itself.

- Renaming `index.html` to `index.cshtml`
- Updating the `index` entry in `.angular-cli.json` to `index.cshtml`
- And then build normally using the CLI

I tested this with a new project and seemed to work well with both a dev build (`ng b`) as well as production (`ng b -prod -aot`). You may also try actually including some server code, though you may run into some parse errors if the compiler finds invalid markup.

Comment: I do need to include some server code, like including 'dir="ltr"' in the html tag, and a short iife to set window['_app_base']. I think the view needs to have "@{ Layout = null }" included at the top as well.

Comment: The html attribute and the iife should be preserved without issue. Most people don't know that you can actually modify the index.html and the changes will be included in the output index.html. Like I mention, you might try including the server code and see if it can still compile.

Comment: Works as advertised. The razor syntax didn't cause any conflicts.

Comment: Elegant solution. Am I correct to assume that because they are cshtml they live in the views folder and not in wwwroot ?

Comment: You are correct Muqeet. I am moving the cshtml file out of wwwroot.

Answer (score 0):

this is a gulp solution,

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');

gulp.task('default', function () {
    copy('<your html path>', 'cshtml file name', '<destination path>');
});

function copy(src, filename, dest) {
    gulp.src(src)
        .pipe(rename(filename))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dest));
}
```